# Maven build produces a WAR with web.xml only

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans, war

I'm using NetBeans and Maven build.  Please bear with me as I'm new to Maven:

When building a WebApp (servlets), the build completes successfully, but the WAR file does not have any classes or JARs with dependencies.  The classes are in the target directory file structure, but not added to the WAR.

I tried different things, including jar-with-dependencies plugin and maven-jar-plugin, but that only generates JARs outside of the WAR file with the required classes and dependencies' JARs.  WAR only has web.xml.

Tried the archiveClasses and attachClasses for the maven-war-plugin separately and together to no avail.

Any help and wisdom will be greatly appreciated!

POM:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.msol</groupId>
        <artifactId>PRESTService</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    
        <name>PRESTService</name>
    
        <properties>
            <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>        
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>        
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>        
          
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>
       
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jettison</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
                <version>2.29.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
            </dependency>        
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
              <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
              <version>4.5.10</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
              <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
              <version>4.5.10</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>PentairSystem</groupId>
                <artifactId>PentairSystemComponents</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>G:\PC\PController\dist\PController.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pi4j-device</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pi4j-gpio-extension</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>pi4j-service</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
                                                                                                                                    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
       
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <compilerArguments>
                            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                        </compilerArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    <!--                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>   -->
    
                        <packagingIncludes>G:\ctrl\Controller\dist\Controller.jar</packagingIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                <silent>true</silent>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                        <version>7.0</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                        
    <!--                                        
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>
    
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.2.0</version>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>make-a-jar</id>
                      <phase>compile</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
    -->              
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMDMc.png
```

Comment: Please add your POM to the question.

Comment: I did, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: Was expecting .class files and .jar (library) files packaged into the WAR.  Only have the WEB-INF and META-INF dirs with web.xml, nothing else.

Comment: What command did you run? `mvn clean package`?

Comment: I'm using NetBean, which calls Maven from the UI.  When I select Clean & Build, looks that it issues clean install to Maven.  There is an option to enter Maven goals, so I re-run it with clean package.  Same output.  Generated: PRESTService-1.jar (has all the project classes), PRESTService-1.war (essentially just web.xml), PRESTService-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar (has all project classes and library dependencies).

Comment: First of all, please don't try to run the Maven jar plugin or the Maven assembly plugin (for jar-with-dependencies)  on a war project. This does not help or work. Secondly, you package your classes as separate jar (archiveClasses option). Is this your plan?

Comment: Commented  jar plugin and jar-with-dependencies out.  No, that was not my intent.  Removed the "archiveClasses option"  Now it generates a.jar with the project classes and a WAR with web.xml.

Comment: It was the <packagingIncludes>G:\ctrl\Controller\dist\Controller.jar</packagingIncludes> in the WAR plugin.  So, I now have all the classes and libs, EXCEPT for the one noted above from another NetBeans project.  Can a local JAR file be included somehow?

Comment: Solved that by adding webResources.  All good now